# Calling REST API from MVC Controller (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

EDIT --

This is a stupid question - please ignore it. Going away to learn Java properly.

--

I want to create an API that can be used externally, but I also want to create my own front end to the same API.

If I create an MVC controller & a REST controller in the same app, can I call the REST API from the MVC controller without making an "external" http call, which seems a bit wasteful?

(EDIT - originally linked to another question but it ws wrong. Can't find the right one so removed).

Obviously raises the further question of whether I should or not, but that is, I suppose, subjective. As an aside I'd welcome opinion on that.

EDIT 2 (to add some code in response to chrylis)

So if I create a class like this (example copied from a tutorial somewhere)

```
public class Greeting {
    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }   
}
```

and a rest controller like this which if called directly from the browser will return json data :

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
    
}
```

Then I call it from my HTML controller like this :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        
        Greeting gr=new Greeting(1,"Hi");
        logger.info(gr.getContent());
        
        model.addAttribute("modelName",gr.getContent());
        return "home";
    }
}
```

is that what you mean? It seems to work. The only issue I see is that I'm working on the class directly and not performing the action of the rest api.

Actually, even as I write this I realise this isn't what you meant, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually how I handle my own Web applications. For a `Person` resource, create a `PersonRestController` that returns a `PersonResource` REST representation, and inject the `PersonRestController` into a `PersonHtmlController`. The handler methods on the HTML controller call the REST controller and feed the `PersonResource` (and other relevant attributes) to the model for the HTML template.

Comment: thanks. Would be very grateful if you could you explain or point me to somewhere that would help with that injection bit. I am new to all of this and whilst I am searching I'm not sure I'm using the right terms.

Also, I have been reading about testing using MockMvc, which seems to do something similar to what I'm looking for. I assume that would be no good to use a testing method? Just a thought.

Comment: It might also be relevant that the REST api is returning a json packaged response.

Comment: @beigerac Spring MVC `@RestController`s return POJOs, and you can inject controllers and call methods on them just like any other Spring bean.

Comment: I added some code to the question in response to this, though I think I've misunderstood.